# Regex capture indented block names

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do a regex match for a string output like

```
  awfjioawjeawef oiajweoifjawoief
  oiawjobjoia oiafwjeoifawjeiofw
Start of my Desired Text
  indented group 1                {some random text}
  indented group 2                {some random text}
    sub indented group 1          {some large random 
                                   ...
                                   text}
    sub indented group 2          {some random text}
  indented group 3
    sub indented group 3
  indented group 4                {some large random 
                                   ...
                                   text}
  indented group 5                {some random text}
End of my Desired Text
   non-indeted group1             {some random text}
   non-indented group2            {some large random 
                                   ...
                                   text}
```

Ultimately I want to be able to get the names of the "indented groups" like this:

```
['indented group 1', 'indented group 2', 'sub indented group 1', 'sub indented group 2', 'indented group 3', 'sub indented group 3', 'indented group 4', 'indented group 5']
```

I'm trying to use this regex:

```
(\n\s+([\w\s\-\,]+).*\{)+
```

However, I can't get it capture like above, where it ends up capturing outside the "Start of my Desired Text" and "End of my Desired Text". Any advice? (here's the regex link https://regex101.com/r/LsxhlH/1/)
I would like to get everything in one regex expression as opposed to splitting to multiple.  I can't get submatch inside match to work very well.

Comment: Showing your real data will be more useful. Also add a language tag.

Comment: Your link suggests your creating this in Python. If that is the case, you may consider tagging Python too.

Comment: Is there a reason `'sub indented group 3'` appears twice in your desired output?
Does the actual text `Start of my Desired Text` / `End of my Desired Text` exist in your real input?
Your `non-indented group2` actually appears to be indented - so your example is no help in understanding what you are doing. Please provide a real world example and desired outcomes.

Comment: My mistake one the 2nd 'sub intented group 3'.  I updaeted it.  Thats correct, the "Start ..." and "End of .." is not the real input.  I can't publish the real input.  I've tried to simplify it to a regex scenario on the type of match i need to perform from an expected output pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's a 2 step operation.

***1. Get the text between the start/end of desired text:***

```
(?<=Start[ ]of[ ]my[ ]Desiried[ ]Text)[\S\s]+(?=End[ ]of[ ]my[ ]Desiried[ ]Text)
```

https://regex101.com/r/jj8hfQ/1

***2. Use the result from step 1 and run a global findall regex on   that match string to get an array of the names:***

```
(?m)^[^\S\r\n]+([\w\s\-\,]+?)[^\S\r\n]*?(?:\{|\r?\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/LkOIWt/1

Explained:

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 [^\S\r\n]+                    # Required some horizontal whitespace (indent, trim)
 ( [\w\s\-\,]+? )              # (1), The indented name
 [^\S\r\n]*?                   # Trailing horizontal whitespace (trim)
 (?: \{ | \r? \n )             # Required, either a { or a linebreak
```

Comment: This works but is there a way to get evertything in one step?  I should have mentioned this in my description.